# Generate list files with CMake

Tags: gcc, cmake

I hope this is a simple question and I'm just missing something fundamental.

I'm trying to emulate a binary build manager for an embedded Cortex-M0 target using a CMake project. I'm having some trouble figuring out how to generate list files for each dependency of my executable target.

The current build system, when building a file called `main.c` passes `-Wa,-alh=.\CortexM0\ARM_GCC_493\Debug/main.lst` as an argument to gcc. I can't figure out how to get CMake to use the current filename without the extension to save the file.

I've looked at the [get_filename_component](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/get_filename_component.html) command, but it appears only to get the filename of the output:

```
add_executable(TestExe main.c)
get_filename_component(curr_name TestExe NAME_WM)
message(${curr_name})
```

As expected, this prints `TestExe` instead of the hoped for `main`

Is there a simple variable I'm overlooking that I could put in my toolchain file's CMAKE_C_FLAGS like `-Wa,-alh=${CURR_SOURCE}.lst`? Or some other method that I'm not seeing?

System info:

- Windows 10
- Msys shell
- CMake 3.7.2
- arm-none-eabi-gcc v4.9.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Expansion Rules](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables#Expansion_Rules) and extend [`CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILE_OBJECT.html):

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT "${CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT} -Wa,-alh=<OBJECT>.lst")
```

But there is unfortunately

- no Expansion Rule that does give the current source file without path and extension
- so you will get in the above example `main.c.o.lst` as an output name

<sub>Footnote: In CMake generated makefile projects, if you just need the assembly file can just do `make main.s` or for the pre-processed file `make main.i`.</sub>

Comment: There isn't a sub section called "Expansion Rules" in the reference, even on the redirected place (title *"Useful Variables"*) - (moved to a different place?).